# Can you drop tier? (Season 4)

Tags: league-of-legends

This question has been already asked regarding Season 3, but if I recall correclty,  Riot stated something in the lines of "You can drop tiers in Season 4". So I want to know if this is the case, now that Season 4 has started..?

**edit:** Since some people obviously don't know that there is a difference between Season 3 (before December 2013) and Season 4 (from Mid January 2014), I want to state this clearly again: I am asking about dropping tiers in **Season 4**. This is not a duplicate to [the same question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108250/can-you-drop-tiers-in-lol-ranked?lq=1), since it was asked by the time of **Season 3**, which means through patches the system can be (and has) changed. So either the other question question (as well as the answers) has to be updated, or this question is just plain and simple **not a duplicate**.

Comment: I don't know why this question gets closed, since it cleary asks about Season 4 - As we can see in the answer from Lyrical, with 4.1 it actually **is possible** to drop a tier. The other question does not cover the new patch for Season 4, nor does any answer give a hint about it. The selected answer there just states that you can only drop a tier by decy through inactivity, **which is not correct anymore**.

Comment: old questions should be *kept up-to-date* instead of opening new ones asking the same thing, but at a different time.

Comment: @3ventic Even though I tend to agree with that statement, I think that editing a old question (especially regarding just this detail) won't give it an answer / edited answer anytime soon.

Comment: @Toby The solution to that is to offer a bounty.

Comment: The linked question doesn't even mention a season. Answers for both S3 and S4 are valid.

Comment: @3ventic This makes it even worse, since someone who searches the answer will find the old question, as well as the chosen answer. Since it nowhere states the Season he will most likely just take the answer for granted, even though it is not up to date anymore.

Comment: You can edit the answer, and add a note about it. Most people will find that question instead of this one, too, so it's better to update that instead of keep misleading the people who google.

Comment: Can we reopen this? The marked duplicate question/answer was clearly referring to season 3.. The correct approach would be to edit the duplicate question and specify it is season 3. Adding new answers that are cross season to the original just hides the information and makes the duplicate question answers conflicting and confusing

Comment: Please remember to remove the edit if/when it is reopened :D Don't need that mucking up the question text

Comment: @Brian This has already been asked.  It had not specified season, and by a third season, you know there's going to be more.  As we have already said, the correct response is to update the old question.  That way, rather than having people ask this question again every season, we just update an answer with the correct information.  Questions are meant withstand the test of time; by mentioning any sort of time-based item (patch version, season, etc.), you're inherently making the question only last for a small period of time.  So we remove that, and have a proper question, no matter the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the **[4.1 Patch Notes](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-41-notes)**:

- Tier demotions and shielding have been added

  - Once you enter a new tier, you’ll have a set number of games where you are invulnerable to dropping out
  - After you play these games, if you fall a full tier below your placement in terms of MMR, a demotion warning will appear in your profile (IE: A Gold V player playing at a Silver V skill level would see this warning)
  - Continuing to lose games at 0 LP will result in a demotion to division I of the next lower tier